# Redirect to post details from creating new_post doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a section named forum in my project where users can post and discuss.

While creating a new post, when I try to save my new post as a user (pic)[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZEnw.png) occurs. I am trying to save the username as well to show further which user creates the post.

Actually problem shows when I try to save [this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sura.png).

I tried in following way:

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user_id =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete =models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 500, blank = False)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields=['title','description']
    template_name = 'post_form.html'

    def self(self, request):
        model.user_id =  request.user.id
        return redirect('website:details',{'post': model})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import UserFormView  , index , user_login,Forum,Details,PostCreate

app_name = 'website'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',index,name = 'index'),
    url(r'^register/$',UserFormView.as_view(),name = 'register'),
    url(r'^login/$', user_login, name= 'login'),
    url(r'^forum/$',Forum, name = 'Forum'), 
    url(r'details/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$',Details,name= 'details'),
    url(r'add/$',PostCreate.as_view(),name = 'newPost')
]
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages. Copy and paste the full traceback.

Comment: Note that Django 1.9 is end of life and doesn’t receive security updates. You should upgrade to at least 1.11, or better Python 3 and Django 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the user in `def self`, but this code belongs in the `form_valid` method.

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):

    model = Post
    fields=['title','description']
    template_name = 'post_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user_id = self.request.user # see note below
        post.save()       
        return redirect('website:details', post=post)
```

As an aside, it would be a good idea to rename your foreign key `user_id` to `user`. At the moment, `post.user_id` is the related user, and `post.user_id_id` is the id of the user. It would be better if you changed your model to:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete =models.CASCADE)
```

Then `post.user` would be the user, and `post.user_id` would be the id of the user. If you make this change, you'll have to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` to change the field name.

Comment: I just copied your code and migrated my database. But it gives me new error. please check the post.

Comment: The `form_valid` method was missing `form`.

Comment: If I add form as another parameter, It shows request is not defined.. But I used request.user to save username.

Comment: It’s `self.request`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using in your form_valid method instead of redirect.

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:details', kwargs={'post_id': post.id,}))
```